# Insert a column in specified position in a excel sheet and fill it with NaN values

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.insert(7, "Photo Order", np.nan)
print(df.head) 
pd.to_excel(df)
```

I use this code and it updates the whole excel file but I want to write a specific column name "Order" in excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, the following modification tpo your code:

```
   pd.to_excel(df['Order'])
```